# Website Behavior Data in Sales Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, analytics, website-integration, sales

We have a business using both Sales Cloud & Marketing Cloud. We'd like to know what our leads did during their visits on our website (pages visited, documents downloaded, etc.). What is the best approach to do so? Can I use the collect.js tracking code of Marketing Cloud and then send that information in Sales Cloud?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could go with collect.js, but it will require a lot of customisations in order for the data to reach Sales Cloud and be stored in a structured way. The data received from Web & Mobile Analytics can be passed on to the PI data extensions (starting with PI_ and IGO_) but you will still need to process the data heavily, in order to turn this data into some useful insights. And then, you will still need find a way to populate one or more custom objects in Sales Cloud, as the MC Connector only does a one way sync.

Depending on your needs, [Pardot](https://www.pardot.com/) might be a good option, since it has both tracking scripts and [Page Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pardot_automation_page_action_considerations.htm&type=5) as part of the solution, allowing you to act on the behaviour directly in Sales Cloud. The same goes for documents downloaded, which can't be done using the standard implementation of MC collect.js.

Pardot has an [Engagement History Lightning Component](http://help.pardot.com/customer/portal/articles/2635301-engagement-history-for-lightning-reference), showing you all the relevant actions for Leads/Contacts.

Please provide more info, if more specific help is needed.

Comment: Thanks fo your answer Lukas. The end goal is that our sales rep have more information about the user behavior on our website in order to have more meaningful communications with them . For example, if they know that a user visited a specific product category on our website, they would be able to have a more relevant conversation with our potential customer.

Comment: You CAN do it using collect.js, but then you will have to query the PI_CONTENTVIEWS,  PI_CONTENTATTRIBS and IGO_PROFILES, to build a browsing profile for a lead, output the result into a Data Extension, and using e.g. SSJS, push this to a custom object SalesCloud - using Lead or Contact ID as a mapping key. When dealing with a lot of activity, this could significantly increase your data storage on Sales Cloud.